# Qt QObject::connect() function cannot be connected

Tags: c++, qt5

I have the code like this:

```
class MyListView : public QListView
{
public:
    MyListView();
    ~MyListView();

public slots:
    void insertData();
    void deleteData();
    void showData();

private:
    QStringListModel *model;
    QListView *listView;
};
```

And the constructor is like:

```
MyListView :: MyListView()
{
    QStringList data;
    data << "Letter A" << "Letter B" << "Letter C";
    model = new QStringListModel;
    model->setStringList(data);

    listView = new QListView;
    listView->setModel(model);

    /* the three buttons */
    QPushButton *insertBtn = new QPushButton(QObject::tr("insert"),this);
    QObject::connect(insertBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(insertData()));
    QPushButton *deleteBtn = new QPushButton(QObject::tr("delete"),this);
    QObject::connect(deleteBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(deleteData()));
    QPushButton *showBtn = new QPushButton(QObject::tr("show"),this);
    QObject::connect(showBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showData()));

    /* layout */
    QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    btnLayout->addWidget(insertBtn);
    btnLayout->addWidget(deleteBtn);
    btnLayout->addWidget(showBtn);
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    mainLayout->addWidget(listView);
    mainLayout->addLayout(btnLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

}
```

So I want to connect the push button to the slot functions, but when I compile it, I got the error message as:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QListView::insertData()
```

I think the problem comes from the connect function, in which, "this" is not the right pointer, any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Q_OBJECT macro in your MyListView

From Qt API docs:

> Notice that the Q_OBJECT macro is mandatory for any object that
>   implements signals, slots or properties. You also need to run the Meta
>   Object Compiler on the source file. We strongly recommend the use of
>   this macro in all subclasses of QObject regardless of whether or not
>   they actually use signals, slots and properties, since failure to do
>   so may lead certain functions to exhibit strange behavior.

So, it should be:

```
class MyListView : public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like the QListView is different with QObject, since when I add the "Q_OBJECT" as you recommended, I got a new error:"undefined reference to 'vtable for MyListView'".

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated issue to me, you may want to repost updated code

Comment: Have you _run qmake_ after you added the Q_OBJECT macro?

Comment: what is the qmake? I program it in the newest Qt, then press the green triangle button to run the code. Most of my code works well but now I am stuck here.

Comment: @yankee2905, it works as what you said, I added the "Q_OBJECT" macro into the class, and then follow Zlatomir's instruction to run qmake. then it works find. I don't understand what is the "qmake" for. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: qmake will generate your makefile. It must be run anytime your Qt dependencies change, or in this case a new Q_OBJECT is declared. Check out http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html